# In Silverlight, when loading XAPs dynamically, can only only the first loaded define an App.xaml?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have four Silverlight 4 apps, for which I'm trying to build a "shell" to host them in, dynamically loading the Xaps on demand, and giving the user the impression they are a single application.

Each application currently has its own App.xaml, which defines a System.Windows.Application.  My question is - if my outer shell app defines an App.xaml, then can the Xap files it loads also define one?  Or must there only be one App.xaml across all the constituent apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other assemblies can define their own App.xaml files, but they won't be executed or referenced.  In my testing, the only App.xaml that gets used/executed is the one that's defined by the first (container) application.  Any reference after that to App.Current will return that particular instance.

Comment: Interesting... my constituent apps each load various styles into the Application resource dictionary.  So, now only my master app.xaml runs, how do I load my various resource dictionaries?  Perhaps programatically instead of declaratively?

Comment: The way that I've been doing it is to "re-" load them all in the master application.  I don't really like it, since it violates DRY, but I haven't figured out a better way.  It might be possible to use generic.xaml for this (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689044/using-mergeddictionaries-in-generic-xaml-in-silverlight-3), but I haven't been able to get that working yet. Perhaps I'm just doing something wrong :-).